# c# how to check if pieces are ordered?

Tags: c#, xna

Picture 1.

[image: properly ordered 2 pieces there can be 3 also]

Picture 2.

[image: if empty space is between pieces its wrong order]

I made method for checking if all pieces are in base or goal if yes it returns true,now i need another method.

If its like on Picture 1. i need to change number of throws to 3 ,if its ordered like on Picture 2 i can allow only 1 throw.

I got 4 goalPositions and 4 piecePositions,and need to check if pieces are ordered on them properly from 54-51 path positions(path is array of 55 fields 0-54) ,if yes return true if not return false.

I am new to C# never had chance to work with order checking till now.

I was trying to do it with 3 int lists goalPositions (populated with 51,52,53,54 path positions),piecePositions(populated with pieces positions with getPosition() method),and piecesOnGoal (reserved for counting pieces on goal positions). but no luck with that.

I'll add some code. Part of Player class with that lists and method for checking pieces in goal or base

```
class Player    {
    protected PieceSet[] pieces;
    Color color;
    int numberOfThrows;
    Dice dice;
    public List<int> goalPositions;
    public List<int> piecePositions;
    public List<int> piecesOnGoal;


    public enum Color
    {
        Yellow, Green, Blue, Red
    }


    public Player(Color color)
    {
        int[] path = new int[55];
        this.color = color;
        dice = new Dice();
        numberOfThrows = 3;
        switch (color)
        {
            case Color.Yellow:
                path = BoardHelper.getYellowPath();
                break;
            case Color.Green:
                path = BoardHelper.getGreenPath();
                break;
            case Color.Blue:
                path = BoardHelper.getBluePath();
                break;
            case Color.Red:
                path = BoardHelper.getRedPath();
                break;
        }
        pieces = new PieceSet[4];
        pieces[0] = new PieceSet(path, 0);
        pieces[1] = new PieceSet(path, 1);
        pieces[2] = new PieceSet(path, 2);
        pieces[3] = new PieceSet(path, 3);


        piecePositions = new List<int>(4);
        piecePositions.Add(pieces[0].getPosition());
        piecePositions.Add(pieces[1].getPosition());
        piecePositions.Add(pieces[2].getPosition());
        piecePositions.Add(pieces[3].getPosition());


        goalPositions = new List<int>(4);
        goalPositions.Add(51);
        goalPositions.Add(52);
        goalPositions.Add(53);
        goalPositions.Add(54);


       piecesOnGoal =new List<int>();
    }

    public bool isAllPiecesInBaseOrGoal()
    {
        if ((pieces[0].getPosition() < 4 || pieces[0].getPosition() > 50) &&
           (pieces[1].getPosition() < 4 || pieces[1].getPosition() > 50) &&
           (pieces[2].getPosition() < 4 || pieces[2].getPosition() > 50) &&
           (pieces[3].getPosition() < 4 || pieces[3].getPosition() > 50))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

And this is how I was thinking to solve my problem: Check if `goalPositions` contains `piecePositions`. If yes, add that position into `piecesOnGoal`. Now I need somehow to check if these `piecesOnGoal` are ordered. If yes, return true. If not, false.

I am open for any suggestion.

```
public bool isAllPiecesAreOrderedInGoal()
{            
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (goalPositions.Contains(piecePositions[i])) 
        {
            piecesOnGoal.Add(piecePositions[i]);
        }                               
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not make a Tile class or an object that will handle this kind of things? You could have a subclass Goal of Tile type. Your tile would contain an object, which would be null or a Piece.

Comment: sorry i dont know how to do that ,i am new to c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a method that checks if any move is possible. A move is possible if there are pieces outside the home or goal or if there are pieces in the goal which have an empty spot before them:

```
bool IsMovePossible()
{
    // check every piece
    for(int iPiece = 0; iPiece < 4; ++iPiece)
    {
        // if it is outside of home or goal, there is a possible move
        if(piecePositions[iPiece] > 3 && piecePositions[iPiece] < goalPositions.First())
            return true;
        // if it is in the goal, check the next position
        if(piecePositions[iPiece] >= goalPositions.First() 
              && piecePositions[iPiece] < goalPositions.Last() 
              && !piecePositions.Any(p => p == piecePositions[iPiece] + 1))
            return true;
    }
    // we have found no piece with a possible move
    return false;
}
```

Then, decide how often the user can roll the dice based on this method's return value. Note that the last check (`piecePositions.Any`) could be done more efficiently if you maintain an inverted map (i.e. for every position, store which piece is on that position). But checking four pieces should be fine.

Comment: I see that first,last and any methods first time in my life i get what is 1. an last . Can you explain me what this part of code does ..... !piecePositions.Any(p => p == piecePositions[iPiece] + 1) i need to know how to use it in my game ...if its not to much

Comment: and if i menage to do that with your code block its my last exam ill need to explain every part of code :D

Comment: this is link to image with possible combinations of piecePositions [link](http://s12.postimg.org/dahv0elil/Untitled.png)

Comment: The `Any` method determines if any element from a collection (in your case the `piecePositions` array) fulfills a given predicate. The predicate is the `p => p == piecePositions[iPiece] + 1)` part, which is actually a function. It takes its argument and denotes it with the symbol `p` (that's the `p => ` part). And the function's result is `p == piecePositions[iPiece] + 1`. So the function returns true if the piece `p` is at the position before the examined piece (`iPiece`). And if there is any, the current piece cannot move.

Comment: hope i get it right cos english is not my native language... for example if piecePositions[0] is currently at 51 position on path,that function without " ! " sign checks if any of other elements from piecesPositions collection is on 52 position ,if there is one it returns true

Comment: Thanks a lot ,i have learned very useful thing from you , i tried to solve my problem on your way ,also figured out other way to do it and no luck with both. VS shows no errors but that method is not working properly ,when i use only that method for checking if pieces are in goal or base from my post under player class it works ,whenever i use lists in method its not working properly ,and cant do check without lists ...  or i can ,but my knowledge is low and cant see the way to do it .

Comment: can i somehow deal with it without lists ,using getPosition() and getNumPieces() from PieceSet class like get position add +1 to it and check with get number of pieces to see if there is a piece on next position on path ? i posted [**Here**](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/jeftosrb/A4gzL) both of classes for that checking method

Comment: Also want to say that i am really sorry for bothering you so much , its important to me ... only that method stands between me and my graduation,and don't have money to pay professional.

Comment: Of course, you can do it without lists. Then the predicate would probably something like `p => p.GetPosition() == pieces[i].GetPosition + 1`. Just to give you an idea. I haven't checked if it actually fits in your code.